# how to show wishlist products in homepage

Tags: magento-1.8, wishlist

How to show wishlist products in magento's home page. Is there any way to bring it with custom block using static blocks.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Answer (score 1):

In your CMS page "HomePage" add

```
{{block type="wishlist/customer_sidebar" name="wishlist_homepage" template="wishlist/sidebar.phtml"}}
```

Or add in the Layout Update XML

```
<reference name="content">
<block type="wishlist/customer_sidebar" name="wishlist_homepage" template="wishlist/sidebar.phtml" />
</reference>
```

Wishlist products are now in the HomePage.

If you want to change the look duplicate for example base/default/template/wishlist/sidebar.phtml to yourTheme/template/wishlist/sidebar.phtml and you are free to do what you want.

In case you want to remove wishlist products from sidebar, in yourTheme/layout/local.xml add :

```
<default>
    <reference name="right">
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>wishlist</name></action>
    </reference>
</default>
```